# I am getting an error while installing helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

Colleagues, good afternoon!
Tell me what could be the problem?
Installation fails with the following error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed post-install: timed out waiting for the condition
Trying to install cert-manager via helm:

```
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
   --namespace cert-manager \
   --create-namespace \
   --version v1.10.0 \
   --debug
```

I checked the pre-version:

```
helm search repo cert-manager
```

I'm trying to install the latest version!
Also I have implemented this:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.10.0/cert-manager.crds.yaml
```

Full install output:

```
install.go:192: [debug] Original chart version: "v1.10.0"
install.go:209: [debug] CHART PATH: /root/.cache/helm/repository/cert-manager-v1.10.0.tgz

client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:229: [debug] checking 39 resources for changes
client.go:250: [debug] Created a new ServiceAccount called "cert-manager-cainjector" in cert-manager

client.go:250: [debug] Created a new ServiceAccount called "cert-manager" in cert-manager

client.go:250: [debug] Created a new ServiceAccount called "cert-manager-webhook" in cert-manager

client.go:250: [debug] Created a new ConfigMap called "cert-manager-webhook" in cert-manager

client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-cainjector"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-controller-issuers"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-controller-clusterissuers"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-controller-certificates"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-controller-orders"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-controller-challenges"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-controller-ingress-shim"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-view"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-edit"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-controller-approve:cert-manager-io"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-controller-certificatesigningrequests"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRole "cert-manager-webhook:subjectaccessreviews"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRoleBinding "cert-manager-cainjector"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRoleBinding "cert-manager-controller-issuers"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRoleBinding "cert-manager-controller-clusterissuers"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRoleBinding "cert-manager-controller-certificates"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRoleBinding "cert-manager-controller-orders"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRoleBinding "cert-manager-controller-challenges"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRoleBinding "cert-manager-controller-ingress-shim"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRoleBinding "cert-manager-controller-approve:cert-manager-io"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for ClusterRoleBinding "cert-manager-controller-certificatesigningrequests"
client.go:521: [debug] Patch ClusterRoleBinding "cert-manager-webhook:subjectaccessreviews" in namespace
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for Role "cert-manager-cainjector:leaderelection"
client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for Role "cert-manager:leaderelection"
client.go:250: [debug] Created a new Role called "cert-manager-webhook:dynamic-serving" in cert-manager

client.go:512: [debug] Looks like there are no changes for RoleBinding "cert-manager-cainjector:leaderelection"
client.go:521: [debug] Patch RoleBinding "cert-manager:leaderelection" in namespace kube-system
client.go:250: [debug] Created a new RoleBinding called "cert-manager-webhook:dynamic-serving" in cert-manager

client.go:250: [debug] Created a new Service called "cert-manager" in cert-manager

client.go:250: [debug] Created a new Service called "cert-manager-webhook" in cert-manager

client.go:250: [debug] Created a new Deployment called "cert-manager-cainjector" in cert-manager

client.go:250: [debug] Created a new Deployment called "cert-manager" in cert-manager

client.go:250: [debug] Created a new Deployment called "cert-manager-webhook" in cert-manager

client.go:521: [debug] Patch MutatingWebhookConfiguration "cert-manager-webhook" in namespace
client.go:521: [debug] Patch ValidatingWebhookConfiguration "cert-manager-webhook" in namespace
client.go:310: [debug] Starting delete for "cert-manager-startupapicheck" ServiceAccount
client.go:339: [debug] serviceaccounts "cert-manager-startupapicheck" not found
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:310: [debug] Starting delete for "cert-manager-startupapicheck:create-cert" Role
client.go:339: [debug] roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cert-manager-startupapicheck:create-cert" not found
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:310: [debug] Starting delete for "cert-manager-startupapicheck:create-cert" RoleBinding
client.go:339: [debug] rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cert-manager-startupapicheck:create-cert" not found
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:310: [debug] Starting delete for "cert-manager-startupapicheck" Job
client.go:339: [debug] jobs.batch "cert-manager-startupapicheck" not found
client.go:128: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:540: [debug] Watching for changes to Job cert-manager-startupapicheck with timeout of 5m0s
client.go:568: [debug] Add/Modify event for cert-manager-startupapicheck: ADDED
client.go:607: [debug] cert-manager-startupapicheck: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:568: [debug] Add/Modify event for cert-manager-startupapicheck: MODIFIED
client.go:607: [debug] cert-manager-startupapicheck: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
^XError: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed post-install: timed out waiting for the condition
helm.go:84: [debug] failed post-install: timed out waiting for the condition
INSTALLATION FAILED
main.newInstallCmd.func2
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:141
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.5.0/command.go:872
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.5.0/command.go:990
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.5.0/command.go:918
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
    enter code here
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to find a fix for the same ? I am trying to install opentelemetry operator and for this i need to install cert-manager.

Comment: Have you tried setting the value `installCRDs=true` in the helm install command?
i.e.

`helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
   --namespace cert-manager \
   --create-namespace \
   --version v1.10.0 \
   --debug \
   --set installCRDs=true`